# Cannot use grunt on simple Yeoman angular

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, yeoman

Trying to just startup a simple angular app via Yeoman, using steps in this guide
http://www.sitepoint.com/kickstart-your-angularjs-development-with-yeoman-grunt-and-bower/

and get this error when trying to run `grunt` or `grunt server`:

```
Loading "Gruntfile.js" tasks...ERROR
Error: Cannot find module 'load-grunt-tasks'
Warning: Task "default" not found. Use --force to continue.
```

Here are my versions:

```
yo --version && grunt --version && bower --version
1.1.2<
grunt-cli v0.1.13
grunt v0.4.4
1.3.1
```

See screencast of this in action:
http://screencast.com/t/4ToPw3SlL2

Comment: Can you please post your Gruntfile.js? It has probably some wrong format

Comment: When in the project directory what happens when you type `npm list load-grunt-tasks`?

Comment: npm list load-grunt-tasks
da@0.0.0 c:\workspace\da
└── load-grunt-tasks@0.4.0

Comment: Here is my Gruntfile.js:  https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3J7zzEKdihiWS1nUEY1RU9LNkU/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Hi, please pick the answer for this question.. Thanks

Answer (score 17):

I just encountered the same problem today, managed to resolve it with the answers here.

Basically I needed to update npm to latest version,
by using this command (the npm which came with Node-v0.10.29 package was outdated)

```
npm update npm -g
```

or

```
sudo npm update npm -g (i used this command on my mac)
```

Then type this command

```
npm --version (it should show 1.5.0-alpha-4 or later version)
```

Then type the grunt serve command

```
grunt serve
```

If you still have issues, then try running these commands

```
npm install
```

or

```
sudo npm install (i used this command on my mac)
```

Then try grunt serve command again,

```
grunt serve
```

This time, it worked for me.

If it didn't, then try this command

```
bower install (i did not have to use this command)
```

Comment: Great Henry Neo, after a long search it works! Thanks.

Comment: Hi Sergio, Happy to help :)

Answer (score 6):

Run the following commands from the directory that has the `Gruntfile.js` for your project:

```
npm install
npm install -g bower
bower install
```

This will install all npm and bower based dependencies for your project.

In the screencast at 1:18 it shows install errors tied to at least `multimatch`. `load-grunt-task`is dependent on `multimatch`.

Comment: this didn't work.  I tried updating to latest npm 1.4.6, still no luck

Comment: When you use `npm install` does the output end with an error and a message about a log file?

Comment: Thanks Jason.  I ended up manually installing latest npm via a zip file. Now on 1.4.6.  After doing that I'm able to make a new directory, run 'yo angular', and then 'grunt serve'.  That brings up the web app in Chrome as expected.  I wasn't clear on the command to update npm via command line.  I've read about doing a 'npm install npm', but that didn't work.  I grabbed the zip from here an unpacked into my install dir:  http://nodejs.org/dist/npm/

Comment: updating to latest npm using 'sudo npm update npm -g' worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Installed "load-grunt-tasks" module locally

ie

```
npm install load-grunt-tasks
```

instead of

```
npm install -g load-grunt-tasks
```